# C Buffer Pointer different memory locations

Tags: c, pointers, memory, buffer

In order to process data, a function requires a pointer to a data buffer.

```
fooFunction(..., uint8_t *buffer, ...)
```

The problem I am facing is that, the data for the buffer is partly in a smaller buffer which is part of the BSS section and the rest (most of the data) are accessable (from an external device) by memory mapping into the CPU address range. Since I want to avoid copying the data into the buffer (resources are limited), I wonder if there is a way to align the memory regions somehow, in order to make sure both buffers (the local one, and the data which is memory mapped) are aligned next to each other, so that I can simply pass the pointer to the buffer to the function.

To make this more clear, this how the buffers are aligned into memory right now:

```
----------------                                   ---------------
| local buffer |   ... somewhere else in memory... | data buffer |
----------------                                   ---------------
 ^
 |
Pointer for fooFunction
```

This is how the buffer should look like for the function:

```
------------------------------
| local buffer | data buffer |
------------------------------
 ^
 |
Pointer for fooFunction
```

Comment: Map the local and data buffer as a whole region,. Then the data buffer will start from an offset inside the mapped region.

Comment: Any such mapping is going to depend on the o/s and will be extremely non-portable. There is no way to control that sort of mapping at that sort of level in standard C or standard POSIX. Maybe you should look at the POSIX scatter/gather functions ([`readv()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/readv.html),
[`writev()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/writev.html)) for inspiration on how your `fooFunction()` might be improved, but I suspect that it is not under your control. On the whole, I think you'll have to bite the bullet and make space.

Comment: For more help, you'll have to at least identify the O/S you are planning to work on.  If there's more than one, you need to identify them all, but you increase the chances that one or more of them won't support what you think you need.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Sorry for leaving out the details about the OS. The code runs on only on a very custome hardware and only has to fit the needs of this specific system. It will never be ported. Imagine a micro-processor with fixed address mapping. As expected, the fooFunction is not under my control. Thank you for pointing out readv()/writev(), but as far as i can see in the POSIX sources, they also just allocate the memory and copy the buffers together.